# SocketException inside IOException

Tags: java, try-catch, ioexception, socketexception

I'm getting java.net.SocketException in the portion of code with try-catch IOException with no output of errors. SocketException is a successor of IOException so why?

```
try {
        Socket net = new Socket(TARGET, PORT);
        sendRawLine("GET / HTTP/1.1", net);
        sendRawLine("request", net);
        net.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // System.out.println(e);
    }

java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
    at com.Joorvish.sendRawLine(Joorvish.java:125)
    at com.Joorvish.createSockets(Joorvish.java:99)
    at com.Lorento.run(Lorento.java:15)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:113)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(StreamEncoder.java:291)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(StreamEncoder.java:295)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(StreamEncoder.java:141)
    at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(OutputStreamWriter.java:229)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(BufferedWriter.java:254)
    at com.Joorvish.sendRawLine(Joorvish.java:125)
    at com.Joorvish.createSockets(Joorvish.java:100)
    at com.Lorento.run(Lorento.java:15)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Very simple. For why you need to read a liner here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/SocketException.html if you need further help paste your code and tell us what you did and what are you expecting?

Comment: @chiastic-security line 15 is just exucutes a method with this code

Comment: `at com.Joorvish.sendRawLine(Joorvish.java:125)
    at com.Joorvish.createSockets(Joorvish.java:99)` This makes me suspect that `sendRawLine` is somehow used wrongly. Do you have some Docu about that method?

Comment: You need to post the whole of the method that this code appears in, along with its signature, and also line 15 that invokes it.

Comment: @Andy So you need to post the code of `sendRawLine()` for evaluation. Surely this is obvious? and the request for the code? and the stack trace? How exactly do you expect people to help you here? Magic?

Comment: @EJP that's realy does't matter, thanks. so the question is solved.

Comment: It doesn't matter to you that you've wasted a substantial amount of time here over a problem that could have been identified in seconds if you had provided adequate information in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe

This means you've written to a connection that has already been closed by the peer. The reason for that is almost certainly the invalid HTML that you appear to be writing.